# Pushing elements to a nested object in Javascript (Socket.io)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, socket.io, push

I'm getting crazy with this one. I'm new to Javascript, I already did this with PHP in bidimensional arrays but i'm running out of options with JS.

I'm trying to get started with Socket.io and I want to create an object (or array) to handle Rooms and Users on it.

For example, I would want to manage it like this:

```
rooms = {
        roomname: [
            {
                id: id1,
                name: "foo",
            },
            {
                id: id2,
                name: "bar",
            },
        ],
        roomname2: [
            {
                id: id3,
                name: "Juan",
            },
            {
                id: id4,
                name: "Pablo",
            },
        ],
    };
```

This is part of the code and what i've done so far.

```
//Client side is sending: 
socket.emit("join", { name, room, img });
      
//Server side is getting:
const { addUser } = require("./functions.js");
    socket.on("join", ({ name, room, img }, callback) => {
        const { error, user } = addUser({
            id: socket.id,
            name,
            room,
            img: img,
        });
    });

//And addUser function is:
rooms = {};
const addUser = ({ id, name, room, img }) => {
    const user = { id, name, img, room };
    rooms = { ...rooms, [room]: [] };
    rooms[room].push(user);
    
    console.log(rooms)

}
```

And when I open two clients and try to enter two differents rooms I get something like this:

```
{
  'room123': [
    {
      id: 'PdKPyzXv64Wt2YPlAAAO',
      name: 'jugador76749',
      img: '0',
      room: 'room123',
    }
  ],
  'room999': [
    {
      id: 'PdKPyzXv64Wt2YPlAAAO',
      name: 'jugador4344',
      img: '0',
      room: '999',
    }
  ]
}
```

BUT, if i try to join the same room I get only the last user:

```
  'room999': [
    {
      id: 'PdKPyzXv64Wt2YPlAAAO',
      name: 'jugador4344',
      img: '0',
      room: '999'
    }
  ]
```

I know I'm reseting the array everytime I do this:
`rooms = { ...rooms, [room]: [] };`
but i can't find a way to initialize the array before.

I appreciate your help,

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think instead of reseting room like you said just check if it's there?

```js
rooms = {};
const addUser = ({ id, name, room, img }) => {
    const user = { id, name, img, room };
    if (!rooms.hasOwnProperty(room)) {
        rooms[room] = [];
    }
    rooms[room].push(user);
    console.log(rooms);
};
```

Change your addUser function to this and try it out?

Edit: don't create unnecessary pointer's/referances to an object in nodejs. It's consuming more memory so i believe you can just remove `user` variable and push it directly:

```js
rooms = {};
const addUser = ({ id, name, room, img }) => {
    // const user = { id, name, img, room };
    if (!rooms.hasOwnProperty(room)) {
        rooms[room] = [];
    }
    rooms[room].push({ id, name, img, room });
    console.log(rooms);
};
```

Comment: I feel so dumb, it works like a charm. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Meh don't be, there are many ways to do something in js =)